# Solving this linear programming takes forever... is there a more efficient way to solve it?

Tags: inequality, optimization, linear-programming, simplex

I'm supposed to solve the following LP:

$(P_2) \text{ } \text{max}\left\{ 33x_1+13x_2+18x_3 \mid \begin{matrix}
8x_1+3x_2+4x_3 \leq 32\\ 
12x_1+5x_2+7x_3 \leq 51\\ 
5x_1+2x_2+3x_3 \leq 21\\ 
x_1+x_2+x_3 \geq 3
\end{matrix} \right\}$

I have formed the inequations to equations:

$8x_1+3x_2+4x_3+y_1=32$

$12x_1+5x_2+7x_3+y_2=51$

$5x_1+2x_2+3x_3+y_3=21$

$-x_1-x_2-x_3+y_4=-3$

And the solution problem (on my paper "Zielfunktion") is $33x_1+13x_2+18x_3$

I'm supposed to solve it by using simplex algorithm. As you will see below, my solution is very long... I needed about 8 tables and our teacher said that it's solvable with maybe 3 tables. But how? :(

The yellow marks are the pivot elements. [image]

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with the "künstliche Variable". It is commonly use if the constraint is a $\geq$ or a $=$ constraint.

Comment: There is an easier method to calculate the values for the next table. See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2182662/jordan-exchange-pivot-operation-formula-for-non-pivot-rows-and-columns/2183396#2183396 Your method is too time-consuming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See picture below:

[image]

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Maybe you can shortly explain your calculation steps? Because I don't understand why you calculated it like that.

Comment: @cnmesr I've tried to find a way to get only one coefficient for each row. This was obvious for the second row, but I must agree that I had to search a little bit for the other rows.

Comment: In class we have never talked about your way, but it seems very fast :) Is it still simplex algorithm though? Tyvm.

Comment: @cnmesr Have you read my comments ?