# Can someone explain me this Gaussian Method

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, gaussian-elimination

Hello here is my problem:

[image: The extended matrix form]

Can someone just explain me how did he get that inside that circle. I know everything before that just dont know what did he multiply second row with and added to third row in order to get that. If someone can explain me please. And tell me what I need to study more in order to know how to get that stuff in circled area. Sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second row was multiplied by $(1+m)$. Then the corresponding elements were substracted from the elements of the third row.

*second column:*

$1-m^2-(1+m)(1-m)=1-m^2-(1-m^2)=0$

*third column:*

$(1-m)-(1+m)(m-1)=1-m-m+1-m^2+m=-m^2-m+2$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems like this pre-algebra stuff that I need to practice now?

Comment: @GoldSpark It seems so. Especially the application of the [binomial formulas (first, second, third)](https://www.math.utah.edu/online/1010/binom/).

Comment: Thank you! You even told me what exactly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GoldSpark In general you can use the following method to calculate the resulting elements. For me it is the easiest way. See the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2183396/144421).

Comment: Haha thank you. But for now I will stick to what I know untill I master this then I will try other stuff :D

Comment: Nice I did every exercise on that page thanks a lot. I understand now.

Answer (score 3):

Ask yourself: with what do you need to multiply $(1-m)$ to get $1-m^2$ (which is what you want to remove)?

Hint: $1-m^2=1^2-m^2$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yeah but how is then that equal this circles when mutlplied with m-1 and added to 1-m